# Evitar más de una vez duplicados de filas con Jquery

Tags: jquery

Nuevamente, recurro a ustedes para que me puedan ayudar con una inquietud. Tengo una tabla que se va agregando filas de forma dinámica. Tengo un input que contiene la cantidad y dependiendo de esa cantidad se clonara la fila. Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#qt, #discount').on('input paste', function() {
    var qt = $('#qt').val();
    if (qt>20) {
        $('#table_items tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#table_items tbody>tr:last');
        reorder();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Efectivamente, me clona la fila pero más de una vez. Como puedo evitar esto? La fila se debe clonar una sola vez. De antemano, quedo agradecido con la ayuda que me puedan ofrecer.

Comment: Parece que la función se está ejecutando varias veces. Prueba a poner esto como primera línea dentro de la función: `console.log("$('#qt, #discount').on('input paste')");` y mira cuántas veces se ejecuta. Si se ejecuta más de una vez, tendrás que averiguar por qué (es posible que ambos eventos `input` y `paste` se ejecuten a causa de la misma acción, pero no lo sé).

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo por tu respuesta. Efectivamente se estaba ejecutando el evento 4 veces. Después de tanto indagar pude solucionarlo con la función event.stopImmediatePropagation().Ahora si me corre perfecto.